# Will I have to pay taxes in India when I transfer money from a US bank to an Indian bank (Different a/c holders)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, money-transfer

I am based in US and plan to send money to India. [A similar question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/will-i-have-to-pay-taxes-in-india-when-i-transfer-money-from-a-us-bank-to-an-ind) addresses the issue when money is being transferred to my own NRE/NRO/FCNR account in India. I was wondering whether the tax implications (on the money transfer as well as any interest income) change, when I am transferring money to say my spouse/parents' accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You may be subjected to the US **[gift tax](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Gift-Tax)** (if you transfer to anyone other than your legally married spouse or yourself). The receivers will have to deal with the Indian tax laws, which I'm not familiar with.