# send money from US to India in parent's saving a/c

Tags: taxes, india, income, savings-account

If I send money from US to India in my parent's saving account will I have to pay tax in India?

Comment: You might want to disclose your citizenship and US residency/visa status which could affect the answers.

Comment: Here is the same question asked 1 year ago.
http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/tax-implications-in-india-for-sending-money-to-india-from-us

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are Non-Resident Indian for tax purposes, this transaction is not taxable. Indian tax law doesn't qualify "gifts" as taxable income.

Answer (score -4):

I wouldn't send it to India in the first place because their financial system is a bit sketchy, I would look into countries like Germany to send the money to you if you're looking to avoid high taxes with a very stable financial system

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't really an answer to the question asked.